# Issue Related to Join in MS Access Database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am using the following query in an MS Access database:

```
SELECT SD.RollNo, SD.Name , ED.ExamName, (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT innerED.StudentId 
        FROM ExamDetails innerED 
        WHERE innerED.StudentId=SD.StudentId 
    )
) AS StudentId
FROM StudentDetails SD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ExamDetails ED 
    ON SD.StudentId= ED.StudentId
```

Whenever I execute this query, a dialog box comes up and asks for the value of the parameter SD.StudentId.  Why is it asking for this, and how do I stop it from doing so?

Comment: I would not alias the count as studentID, does StudentDetails contain a field studentid?

Comment: yes studentId is primary key of StudentDetails

Comment: Did you try with a different alias in the subquery? `(Count ....)) As StuCount`

Comment: You might be able to do this same thing with a strategic group by. Correlated Sub Queries in Access can be finicky.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access does not understand the SELECT statement on the Count (*) Aggregate.  To Access the SQL Statement looks like this.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT innerED.StudentId
 FROM ExamDetails innerED 
 WHERE innerED.StudentId=SD.StudentId
```

Because the alias AS STUDENTID comes after the end of the statement, this Select statement doesn't recognize it, so it has no idea what .StudendID is so it assumes it's a parameter.

MS Access, when faced with a parameter that has not been identified in the query itself will prompt the user for a value.

Rewrite the query so that this Select statement can identify all the table sources.