# Issue Related to Parameter Value in Query in MS-ACCESS Database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Isssue Related to Join in MS Access Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976336/isssue-related-to-join-in-ms-access-database)

I have a database file in MS-Access database file..

I have following Query :

```
SELECT 
    (select count (*)
     from (select distinct prs_PersonId
           from tb_person
           where prs_personId = PR.prs_personId)) 
FROM tb_Person PR left outer join tb_personDepartment PD
        on PR.prs_PersonId = PD.pd_personId;
```

whenever i execute this query i get one input box and it ask to enter Parameter value of PR.prs_PersonId
why this happens?? and what is the solution ??

Comment: is that all the query or are you simplifying it? are there more joins, fields, group bys, etc??? becouse sounds like it can be rebuilt more simple?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish in your query to begin with. Are you trying to count the distinct people? I feel like a personID on a person table should be unique, unless you are using surrogate keys or a type 2 method to deal with changing data. Even then, why are you joining to departments? Like others have suggested, try simplifying your query, maybe you spelled or aliased something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, Access can't use values external to subqueries inside the subquery, so:

```
SELECT 
    (select count (*) 
     from (
         select distinct prs_PersonId 
         from tb_person 
         where tb_person.prs_personId = 
            /* PR.prs_personId   is not valid here  */
            /* use a constant like */  1  /* just to test that this is the "missing" parametrer. Of course, it won't give correct results, but will run */
         )
     )  As ACount
from tb_Person PR 
left outer join tb_personDepartment PD
on PR.prs_PersonId = PD.pd_personId
```

And then reformulate the query, perhaps something like:

```
SELECT prs_PersonId, count(*) As ACount
FROM tb_person 
GROUP BY prs_PersonId
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is really very confusing.

If you want to know the number of persons in `tb_person`, why are you joining with `tb_personDepartment`?

In a well designed database the `prs_PersonId` must be unique. Either because it is the primary key or because it has a unique index. Therefore the `DISTINCT` seems to be superfluous. (I assume that the persons table is on the many-side of a one-to-many relationship with the departments table. I.e.: The departements table is used as a lookup table from which you can select one department per person.)

If you specify a `prs_PersonId` in the WHERE-clause the result will always be either `0` or `1`. Retrieving the number of persons could be simplified to

```
SELECT Count(*) As PersonCount
FROM tb_Person
WHERE ...
```