# Issue Related to Combining SubQuery with Join in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Isssue Related to Join in MS Access Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976336/isssue-related-to-join-in-ms-access-database)

I have a database file in MS-Access database file..

I have following Query :

```
Select RGN.rgn_regionId,RGN.rgn_titleGuj AS Center,

(Select COUNT(*) from (select Distinct PRS.prs_personId From tb_personDepartment PD,tb_person PRS Where PD.pd_designationId = 1 And PD.pd_personId = PRS.prs_personId And PRS.prs_centerId = RGN.rgn_regionId And PRS.prs_attandanceStatus = 'Y')) As SKAt

From tb_person PRS,tb_personDepartment PD,tb_region RGN
Where PD.pd_personId = PRS.prs_personId
And PRS.prs_centerId = RGN.rgn_regionId
Group By RGN.rgn_regionId,RGN.rgn_titleGuj
```

Table Structure As Follows

```
select * from tb_person where prs_personId in (3)
--prs_personId   prs_uniqId prs_centerId prs_fName  prs_mName    prs_lName  prs_age   prs_addres   prs_areaId
-- 3                    1       1               abc     abc             abc         12      andn            2
--(1 row(s) affected)

    select * from tb_personDepartment where pd_personId in (3)

    --pd_personId          pd_mahotsavId pd_departmentId pd_designationId pd_MainSK
    ---------------------- ------------- --------------- ---------------- -----------
    --3                    1             41              1                1
    --3                    1             44              2                0
    --3                    1             104             1                1

--(3 row(s) affected)

select * from tb_personMahotsavDetail where pm_personId in (3)

--pm_personId   pm_mahotsavId pm_personStatus pm_sevaDaysH   pm_accommodationRequired pm_utaraPlace  
--------------- ------------- --------------- -------------- ------------------------ -------------  
--3                    1             SS              8           0                        NULL       

--(1 row(s) affected)

select * from tb_person where prs_personId in (3)
-- Single Record

select * from tb_personDepartment where pd_personId in (3)
-- Multiple Record With Same Person Id

select * from tb_personMahotsavDetail where pm_personId in (3)
-- Single Record
```

Comment: Are you saying that the tables are in SQL Server and linked in MS Access? This would make a huge difference to the question!

Comment: In MS Access, you **cannot** use the same aliases in the inner query that you use in the outer query, you have aliased tb_persons as PRS in both etc. The tables you posted do not include `prs_attandanceStatus`, so I cannot see how this query would work in SQL Server when the field / column names do not match your tables.

Answer (score 0):

this happens
when `column name does not exist` or it may have been `misspelled`.

Comment: i have tried same query in SQL Server.. It works Properly.. but doesn't work in MSAccess

Comment: can you show table structure , i will try it at my end.

Comment: you may download this app to generate the script.

http://dbweigher.com/dbwscript.php

Comment: i have edited my Post with table structure :

Comment: i removed `Select COUNT(*) from` in your query and it ran.